# In-depth debugging for UrlFetchApp.fetch() ? Returning - 'Address unavailable'

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Edit - **!!! See answer for answer, this isn't an issue !!!**

Attempting to fetch data from an API during scripting within Google sheets fails with error `Address unavailable: https://url.com/api/endpoint` - I am however successfully able retrieve the data from the endpoint using the exact same request through postman.

I have tried adding `muteHttpExceptions: true` to the headers but it does not return any extra detail. Is there anyway to find more accurately at what point it is failing?

The request gets sent when the user clicks the 'run importer' button which is added to the spreadsheet through the appscript. Snippets of relevant code below:

```
// Appscript.json
    ...
    "urlFetchWhitelist": [
      "https://url.com/"
    ],
    ...

// Code.gs
function onOpen(){
    spreadsheet.addMenu("Importer", [{
        name : "Run importer",
        functionName : "runImporter"
    }]);
}

...
function runImporter(){
    ...
    ApiModule.getAuth();
    ...
}

// Api Module
var getAuth = function() {
    var payload = {};
    payload.grant_type = "password";
    payload.username = properties.getProperty('username');
    payload.password = properties.getProperty('password');
    payload.client_id = properties.getProperty('id');
    payload.client_secret = properties.getProperty('secret');

    payload = JSON.stringify(payload);

    try {
        var url = properties.getProperty('url') + "/api/endpoint";
        var headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        };

        var options = {
            "method":"POST",
            "contentType" : "application/json",
            "headers": headers,
            "payload" : payload
        };

        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        spreadsheet.toast(error, 'Error!');
        throw new Error(error);
    }
};
```

Error received - Error: Exception: Address unavailable: https://url.com/api/endpoint

Comment: @I'-'I Did you mean using 'UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)' ? If so both it and the muted HTTP exceptions responses are still just returning 'Address unavailable'. Logging the response I get 'Exception: Address unavailable: https://url.com/api/endpoint'

Comment: @['-'] Wait, I am an idiot. I completely forgot that the URL i was trying to hit was locked down to a set of IPs so Googles servers could never see it anyway....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait, I am an idiot. I completely forgot that the URL I was trying to hit was locked down to a set of IPs, as the appscript runs on Googles Servers it will never reach the API.